# How can I deactivate the lock screen on Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, power-management, display-settings

I am just setting up a media center based on Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon and have created a user with restricted rights. As the system is to be controlled during operation, it should not go into sleep mode. I have changed the energy settings accordingly. But after a while, the lock screen still appears. I then found this solution on the Internet:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

But I was not successful with this either. Can anyone tell me how I can deactivate the switch to the lock screen?

I'd appreciate any help.

Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it from the command line, run:

```bash
$ gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

I've tested it on Linux Mint 21.2 (Cinnamon 5.8.4) and it works as expected.

You can check if the change has taken effect by going to `System Preferences > Screensaver`. `Lock computer after screensaver starts` should now be unchecked.

Or by using `gsettings` again with the `get` subcommand:

```bash
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have since figured it out myself and it worked exactly as you described.